# How do I test DAO using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm new in unit test, and I'm trying to write some tests for my DAO's. I have followed some tutorials/answers here, but most of them don't apply to my DAO's.

I get this warning when I run the test
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked: 
Wanted but not invoked:
mockConn.prepareStatement();

What is wrong?

```
private ApprovalConditionDAO approvalConditionDAO;
@Mock
DataSource mockDataSource;
@Mock
Connection mockConn;
@Mock
PreparedStatement mockPreparedStmnt;
@Mock
CallableStatement cs;
@Mock
ResultSet mockResultSet;

@Before
public void setUp() throws SQLException {
    approvalConditionDAO = new ApprovalConditionDAO();
    when(mockDataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(mockConn);
    when(mockDataSource.getConnection(anyString(),
                                      anyString())).thenReturn(mockConn);
    when(mockConn.prepareStatement(anyString(),
                                   anyInt())).thenReturn(mockPreparedStmnt);
    doNothing().when(mockConn).commit();
    doNothing().when(mockPreparedStmnt).setString(anyInt(), anyString());
    when(mockPreparedStmnt.execute()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    when(mockPreparedStmnt.getGeneratedKeys()).thenReturn(mockResultSet);
    when(mockResultSet.next()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);
}

@Test
public void testCreateWithNoExceptions() throws SQLException {    
   ArrayList<ApprovalConditionBean> actualValues = approvalConditionDAO.getAllApprovalCondition();

    //verify and assert
    verify(mockConn, times(1)).prepareStatement(anyString());
    verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(1)).execute();
    verify(mockConn, times(1)).commit();
    verify(mockResultSet, times(2)).next();
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("ID");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("EIT_CODE");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("FRIST_KEY_TYPE");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("FRIST_KEY_VALUE");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("FRIST_EIT_SEGMENT");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("OPERATION");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("SECOND_KEY_TYPE");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("SECOND_KEY_VALUE");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("SECOND_EIT_SEGMENT");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("APPROVAL_CODE");
}
```

And this is the Dao that I want to test it.

```
  public class ApprovalConditionDAO extends AppsproConnection {
Connection connection;
PreparedStatement ps;
CallableStatement cs;
ResultSet rs;
RestHelper rh = new RestHelper();


public ArrayList<ApprovalConditionBean> getAllApprovalCondition() {

 ArrayList<ApprovalConditionBean> approvalConditionList =
     new ArrayList<ApprovalConditionBean>();
 try {
     connection = AppsproConnection.getConnection();
     String query =
         "SELECT * FROM "+" "+getSchema_Name()+".XXX_APPROVAL_CONDITION";
     ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
     rs = ps.executeQuery();
     while (rs.next()) {
         ApprovalConditionBean approvalConditionBean = new ApprovalConditionBean();
         approvalConditionBean.setId(rs.getString("ID"));
         approvalConditionBean.setEitCode(rs.getString("EIT_CODE"));
         approvalConditionBean.setFirstKeyType(rs.getString("FRIST_KEY_TYPE"));
         approvalConditionBean.setFirstKeyValue(rs.getString("FRIST_KEY_VALUE"));
         approvalConditionBean.setFirstEitSegment(rs.getString("FRIST_EIT_SEGMENT"));
         approvalConditionBean.setOperation(rs.getString("OPERATION"));
         approvalConditionBean.setSecondKeyType(rs.getString("SECOND_KEY_TYPE"));
         approvalConditionBean.setSecondKeyValue(rs.getString("SECOND_KEY_VALUE"));
         approvalConditionBean.setSecondEitSegment(rs.getString("SECOND_EIT_SEGMENT"));
         approvalConditionBean.setApprovalCode(rs.getString("APPROVAL_CODE"));


         approvalConditionList.add(approvalConditionBean);

     }

 } catch (Exception e) {
     //("Error: ");
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     closeResources(connection, ps, rs);
 }
 return approvalConditionList;

}
```

And this as my AppsproConnection Calss

```
     public static Connection getConnection(boolean commit) {
    if (CommonConfigReader.getValue("CONNECTION_TYPE").equalsIgnoreCase("JDBC")) {
        return getJDBCConnection(commit);
    } else {
        return getDSConnection(commit);
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() {
    if (CommonConfigReader.getValue("CONNECTION_TYPE").equalsIgnoreCase("JDBC")) {
        return getJDBCConnection();
    } else {
        return getDSConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't call the method you wanted to test from the test method.

Comment: Like @Rashin said, in the first line of your test call your method `.getAllApprovalCondition()` before doing the verify.

Comment: it warning me in this line verify(mockConn, times(1)).prepareStatement(anyString()); WantedButNotInvoked: What i should do please? @arnonuem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call the method you wanted to test from the test method.
You don't event have a test object to do so.

```java
class TestClass {
    private MyDao underTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {
        underTest = new MyDao();
        // mocking things...
    }
}
```

And using this test object you have to call the method you actually want to test from a test method.

```java
@Test
public void testCreateWithNoExceptions() throws SQLException {
    // ...

    ArrayList<ApprovalConditionBean> actualValues = underTest.getAllApprovalCondition();

    // assertions
}
```

---

If you cannot manipulate how you get the connection from a static class then you can refactor your method to get a connection from another method in the same class.

```java
public ArrayList<ApprovalConditionBean> getAllApprovalCondition() {
    // ...
    connection = getConnection();
    // ...
}

Connection getConnection() {
    return AppsproConnection.getConnection();
}
```

If you are using like this you can instantiate the test object in a way that you can manage what kind of Connection is returned for tests.

```java
@Before
public void setUp() throws SQLException {
    when(mockConn.prepareStatement(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(mockPreparedStmnt);
    doNothing().when(mockConn).commit();
    doNothing().when(mockPreparedStmnt).setString(anyInt(), anyString());
    when(mockPreparedStmnt.execute()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    when(mockPreparedStmnt.getGeneratedKeys()).thenReturn(mockResultSet);
    when(mockResultSet.next()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);

    underTest = new MyDao(){
        @Override
        public Connection getConnection() {
            return mockConn;
        }
    };
}
```

We are returning the mocked connection from `getConnection`. This method is called from the `getAllApprovalCondition` method. In production it is still providing connection through `AppsproConnection`.

Comment: it warning me in this line
verify(mockConn, times(1)).prepareStatement(anyString()); 
WantedButNotInvoked: 
What i should do please 
@Rashin

Comment: This method is not invoked because the method you want to test is not called.

Comment: I Called it like you say, still the same warning. Any advise please? @Rashin

Comment: Can you show us your dao and `AppsproConnection` classes? As I see you get the connection from `AppsproConnection` but I can't see if you injected the mocked `DataSource` to it.

Comment: Do you actually passing a `DataSource` to `AppsproConnection` anywhere? The problem is that you mocking a `DataSource` so when the `getConnection` method is called on that `DataSource` a mocked connection will be returned. And that's fine but I can't really see if you are using this `DataSource` in the `AppsproConnection` class.

Comment: So what i should use instead of DataSource? @Rashin

Comment: Try set it to protected/public.

Comment: it give me error on "verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(1)).execute();"
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked: 
Wanted but not invoked:
mockPreparedStmnt.execute();
-> at Test.com.appspro.fusionsshr.test.doaTest.ApprovalConditionDAOTest.testCreateWithNoExceptions(ApprovalConditionDAOTest.java:73)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: You are calling `connection.prepareStatement(query);` but mocking `when(mockConn.prepareStatement(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(mockPreparedStmnt);`Try with `when(mockConn.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(mockPreparedStmnt);` The second parameter is not needed.

Comment: is this true  verify(mockResultSet, times(2)).next(); ??